# Simple if else function not returning as expected

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement

Please could someone tell me where I'm going wrong here, I know it's something simple I'm missing so forgive my ignorance but I can't find the error.

```
let day = "Monday"

function alarmTime(day) {
  if (day == "Saturday") {
    return "Set alarm for 8:00am"
  } else if (day == "Friday") {
    return "Set alarm for 5:35am"
  } else if (day == "Sunday" || "Thursday") {
    return "Set alarm for 4:50am"
  } else {
    return "Set alarm for 7:00am"
  }
}

console.log(alarmTime(day));
```

if day is Mon, Tue, Wed then it returns 4:50am??? Why?? It should reach the final else statement and return 7:00am ‍♀️

Comment: "[How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)"

Comment: Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately. Relevant linter warning: [_“Unexpected constant condition”_](//eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-constant-condition).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
day == "Sunday" || "Thursday"
```

This says, if the day is "Sunday" return `true`, else return `"Thursday"`. "Thursday" is a string, so JavaScript converts it to `true`. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy)

Look at the || operator like this
(day == "Sunday") || ("Thursday")

You want to say:

```
day == "Sunday" || day =="Thursday"
```

Bonus tip: use === instead of ==
This is the best way to put it:

```
day === "Sunday" || day ==="Thursday"
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `day == "Sunday" || "Thursday"` evaluates to `Thursday`. Since `if ("Thursday")` evaluates to `true`, it always enters in this block.

What you want to have is `day == "Sunday" || day == "Thursday"`

Answer (score 0):

The `or` operator, `||`, accepts two conditions, not two possible values for a variable

ie:
`foo == "hello" || foo == "hi"`

not `foo == "hello" || "hi"`
as that just evaluates "hi" which returns true like all strings

Answer (score 0):

Below is the updated fuction. It returns 7:00am

```
function alarmTime(day) {
  if (day == "Saturday") {
    return "Set alarm for 8:00am"
  } else if (day == "Friday") {
    return "Set alarm for 5:35am"
  } else if (day == "Sunday" || day == "Thursday") {
    return "Set alarm for 4:50am"
  } else {
    return "Set alarm for 7:00am"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the third `else if` statement does not have a condition for the day to be "**Sunday**" or "**Thursday**". Instead, it has a condition for day to be "**Sunday**" or the boolean value **true**, which will always evaluate to **true**. This causes the code to always return "**Set alarm for 4:50am**".

To fix this, you can change the third `else if` statement to:

```
else if (day == "Sunday" || day == "Thursday")
```

**Example with fixed code:**

```js
let day = "Monday"

function alarmTime(day) {
  if (day == "Saturday") {
    return "Set alarm for 8:00am"
  } else if (day == "Friday") {
    return "Set alarm for 5:35am"
  } else if (day == "Sunday" || day == "Thursday") {
    return "Set alarm for 4:50am"
  } else {
    return "Set alarm for 7:00am"
  }
}

console.log(alarmTime(day));
```